# Anime series set in japanese village. Female protagonist forced to work in a brothel to pay off debts

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am wondering if anyone would be able to help me get the name of an anime series I am looking for.

I only saw one episode.  Here goes ; takes place in a Japanese village, seemed to be hundreds of years ago. A woman is forced to work in a brothel by her husband in order to pay off his debts.

In the brothel she meets a man, tall guy, wearing glasses.  They end up having sex. He comes back a few more times just to visit her. They plan their escape together. They leave the brothel with most of the men from the brothel chasing after them. She waits for him in a small boat on the river.

I don't know if they caught him or if they both escaped.

Comment: Was there anything science fictional or fantasy about this series?

Comment: No. It seemed to be quite realistic.

Comment: Anime isn't on topic on SFF:SE unless it has sci-fi or fantasy content, I'm afraid. If it's simply historical, it's gonna get closed

Comment: If there is no science fiction or fantasy in the anime, then we will not be able to provide any help. Sorry.

Comment: @amflare - If it turns out to be https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samurai_Champloo, then it would be arguably on-topic since the setting is an anachronistic version of medieval Japan

Comment: I second @Valorum; because the style of Mugen is based on capoeira, so in the feudal Japan there weren’t dojos that teach this style. So is not historically accurate, the setting is fantasy.

Comment: @riccs_0x - There are quite literally hundreds of anachronisms; http://www.spookhouse.net/angelynx/comics/anachronisms.html

Answer (score 16):

Sounds similar to Samurai Champloo episode 11 "Gamblers and Gallantry".

Synopsis:

> "Jin comes to the rescue of a lady in distress. He falls in love and
>   tries to rescue this woman from the hard life she has come to face.
>   Will he save her and himself? In the meantime, Mugen trains a
>   rhinoceros beetle for a bug-fighting tournament in which he expects to
>   win money."

Comment: Late 4 min :) https://youtu.be/g9mO3KDh-VM

Comment: Yessssss. It's the one.  Thank you everyone.  I saw it about five years ago and i never thought I'd find it.

Comment: It was on Cartoon Network, which is as about as widely distributed as anime can get, save maybe Netflix.